# ADF run a pipeline taking parameter values from a file for each row

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to bulk load few data files for different entities. Instead of creating separate pipelines for each entities I want to

1. create a control file with columns - EntitiyName, SourceDirectory, SourceFileStartswith, TargetDirectory
2. for each row(each Entity) pipeline will be called where as other three values - SourceDirectory, SourceFileStartswith, TargetDirectory will be passed
3. data file will be picked as supplied SourceDirectory and SourceFileStartswith and to be loaded into path TargetDirectory

Please guide how this will be created in ADF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement,please try ForEach Activity and Copy Activity.

Step1: Create an array parameter to pass the `EntitiyName, SourceDirectory, SourceFileStartswith, TargetDirectory` as json object in array.

[image]

Step2: Refer the parameter in ForEach Activity.

[image]

Step3: Inside ForEach Activity,please use `@item().EntityName`,`@item().SourceDirectory` etc. in Copy Activity to configure the source and sink dataset.